# java Callable FutureTask Excecuter: How to listen to finished task

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, callable, futuretask

I'm quite new to executer services. Liked doing everything myself, but I think it's time to trust these services.

I want to hand by `Executer` a `Runnable`. The executer wraps that in a `FutureTask` and hands it back to me. Now I call poll the `done()` method. But I would like to be notified when then `done()` method would return true.

There is a `get()` method that blocks until the `Runnable` has finished, but then I would need a extra thread for every job, just to see when it's finished.

Can I hand my executer some extra `Callable` to get notified about the task finishing?

What's the way to go here? I could add some code to the end of the `run` method, but then `done()` might still be false...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make a specific assumption of using a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor, then you can use its hook methods; afterExecute() and beforeExecute().

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

They are not as elegant as the ListenableFuture, but it might be an adequate solution provided you need only one type of a "listener" for a given executor instance.

Answer (score 5):

ExecutorCompletionService

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do one task after another its better to do it in the same thread.

```
Executor executor =
final Runnable runnable = 
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         runnable.run();
         // do something after the run() has finished.
    }
 });
```

This way it will do whatever you want done after the runnable in the same thread and you don't need to poll or use another thread.

Comment: I also have multithreading question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130563/how-can-i-terminate-tasks-that-have-timed-out-in-multithreading/). I am not sure how should I use cancel on my future task so wanted to check with you on that. If possible, can you help me out over there.

Answer (score 3):

I'd advise taking a look at the [com.google.common.util.concurrent](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package in [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), specifically the [ListenableFuture](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html) type and the code related to it.

Once the next release (r10) is out, it'll be easy to create an `ExecutorService` that returns `ListenableFuture`s using [MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(ExecutorService)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#listeningDecorator%28java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService%29). You can also currently wrap your `Runnable`s/`Callable`s in a [ListenableFutureTask](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFutureTask.html) yourself.

```
final ListenableFutureTask<?> task = new ListenableFutureTask<Object>(
    runnable, null);
executor.submit(task);
task.addListener(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // do whatever
  }
}, listenerExecutor);
```

Comment: Isn't this a complicated way of Peter Lawrey's approach.

Comment: Maybe with that decorator it could be neat code. When is v.10 coming? Is there some beta to download?

Comment: @irreputable: In Peter's approach, the handling of what to do after the task completes is lumped in as part of the task that is submitted to the executor. If the task were cancelled, for example, you wouldn't find out. As written, an exception in the delegate's `run()` would also cause the part after not to run. Plus you're tying the stuff that happens after to the same thread as the task itself, which you may not want.

Comment: does your framework protect against errors, e.g. OutOfMemoryError? So I can be sure the registered listener will allways be called?

Comment: @Franz: I seem to recall hearing something about July for r10, but there's no official date. You could build the latest source of course, and it's actually pretty easy to extend `AbstractExecutorService` (in 1.6) to do make a listening decorator.

Comment: @Franz: I'm not sure that anything can guarantee what will happen if something like `OutOfMemoryError` occurs (that's why it's an `Error`). That said, when a `FutureTask` runs it does catch any `Throwable` and store it and call `done()`, so it will certainly try to notify listeners when that happens.

Comment: BTW, given source code would not compile. There is no `ExecutorService.submit(FutureTask ft)`, it only accepts `Runnable` and `Callable` as args.