# How can I terminate Tasks that have timed out in multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, callable, futuretask

I need to make a library in which I will have synchronous and asynchronous methods in it.

- `executeSynchronous()` - waits until I have a result, returns the result.
- `executeAsynchronous()` - returns a Future immediately which can be processed after other things are done, if needed.

**Core Logic of my Library**

The customer will use our library and they will call it by passing `DataKey` builder object. We will then construct a URL by using that `DataKey` object and make a HTTP client call to that URL by executing it and after we get the response back as a JSON String, we will send that JSON String back to our customer as it is by creating `DataResponse` object. Some customer will call `executeSynchronous()` and some might call `executeAsynchronous()` so that's why I need to provide two method separately in my library.

Interface:

```
public interface Client {

    // for synchronous
    public DataResponse executeSynchronous(DataKey key);

    // for asynchronous
    public Future<DataResponse> executeAsynchronous(DataKey key);
}
```

And then I have my `DataClient` which implements the above `Client` interface:

```
public class DataClient implements Client {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    // for synchronous call
    @Override
    public DataResponse executeSynchronous(DataKey key) {
        DataResponse dataResponse = null;
        Future<DataResponse> future = null;

        try {
            future = executeAsynchronous(key);
            dataResponse = future.get(key.getTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            PotoLogging.logErrors(ex, DataErrorEnum.TIMEOUT_ON_CLIENT, key);
            dataResponse = new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.TIMEOUT_ON_CLIENT, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
            // does this look right the way I am doing it?
            future.cancel(true); // terminating tasks that have timed out.
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            PotoLogging.logErrors(ex, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_ERROR, key);
            dataResponse = new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_ERROR, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
        }

        return dataResponse;
    }

    //for asynchronous call
    @Override
    public Future<DataResponse> executeAsynchronous(DataKey key) {
        Future<DataResponse> future = null;

        try {
            Task task = new Task(key, restTemplate);
            future = executor.submit(task); 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            PotoLogging.logErrors(ex, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_ERROR, key);
        }

        return future;
    }
}
```

Simple class which will perform the actual task:

```
public class Task implements Callable<DataResponse> {

    private DataKey key;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public Task(DataKey key, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.key = key;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public DataResponse call() {
        DataResponse dataResponse = null;
        String response = null;

        try {
            String url = createURL();
            response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

            // it is a successful response
            dataResponse = new DataResponse(response, DataErrorEnum.NONE, DataStatusEnum.SUCCESS);
        } catch (RestClientException ex) {
            PotoLogging.logErrors(ex, DataErrorEnum.SERVER_DOWN, key);
            dataResponse = new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.SERVER_DOWN, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            PotoLogging.logErrors(ex, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_ERROR, key);
            dataResponse = new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_ERROR, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
        }

        return dataResponse;
    }

    // create a URL by using key object
    private String createURL() {
        String url = somecode;
        return url;
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

When I started working on this solution, I was not terminating the tasks that have timed out. I was reporting the timeout to the client, but the task continues to run in the thread pool (potentially occupying one of my limited 10 threads for a long time). So I did some research online and I found that I can cancel my tasks those have timed out by using `cancel` on `future` as shown below -

```
future.cancel(true);
```

But I wanted to make sure, does it look right the way I am doing in my `executeSynchronous` method to cancel the tasks that have got timedout?

Since I am calling `cancel()` on the`Future` which will stop it from running if tasks is still in the queue so I am not sure what I am doing is right or not? What is the right approach to do this?

If there is any better way, then can anyone provide an example for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If task is still in the queue then cancelling it by simply calling `future.cancel()` is ok but obviously you don't know if that is in the queue. Also even if you ask `future` to interrupt the task it may not work as your task can still be doing something which is ignoring the thread interrupted status.

So you can use the `future.cancel(true)` but you need to make sure that your task (thread) does regard the thread interrupted status. For example as you mentioned you make http call, so you might need to close the http client resource as soon as thread is interrupted.

Please refer to the example below.

I have tried to implement the task cancellation scenario. Normally a thread can check `isInterrupted()` and try to terminate itself. But this becomes more complex when you are using thread pool executors, callable and if the task is not really like `while(!Thread.isInterrupted()) {// execute task}`.

In this example, a task is writing a file (I did not use http call to keep the it simple). A thread pool executor starts running the task but the caller wants to cancel it just after 100 milli seconds. Now future sends the interrupt signal to the thread but the callable task can not check it immediately while writing to file. So to make this happen callable maintains a list of IO resources it is going to use and as soon as future wants to cancel the task it just calls `cancel()` on all IO resources which terminates the task with IOException and then thread finishes.

```
public class CancellableTaskTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CancellableThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new CancellableThreadPoolExecutor(0, 10, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Future<String> future = threadPoolExecutor.submit(new CancellableTask());
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 100) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        System.out.println("Trying to cancel task");
        future.cancel(true);
    }
}

class CancellableThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    public CancellableThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
    }

    @Override
    protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
        return new CancellableFutureTask<T>(callable);
    }
}

class CancellableFutureTask<V> extends FutureTask<V> {

    private WeakReference<CancellableTask> weakReference;

    public CancellableFutureTask(Callable<V> callable) {
        super(callable);
        if (callable instanceof CancellableTask) {
            this.weakReference = new WeakReference<CancellableTask>((CancellableTask) callable);
        }
    }

    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        boolean result = super.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        if (weakReference != null) {
            CancellableTask task = weakReference.get();
            if (task != null) {
                try {
                    task.cancel();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    result = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class CancellableTask implements Callable<String> {

    private volatile boolean cancelled;
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private LinkedList<Object> cancellableResources = new LinkedList<Object>();

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        if (!cancelled) {
            System.out.println("Task started");
            // write file
            File file = File.createTempFile("testfile", ".txt");
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            synchronized (lock) {
                cancellableResources.add(writer);
            }
            try {
                long lineCount = 0;
                while (lineCount++ < 100000000) {
                    writer.write("This is a test text at line: " + lineCount);
                    writer.newLine();
                }
                System.out.println("Task completed");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                writer.close();
                file.delete();
                synchronized (lock) {
                    cancellableResources.clear();
                }
            }
        }
        return "done";
    }

    public void cancel() throws Exception {
        cancelled = true;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        boolean success = false;
        synchronized (lock) {
            for (Object cancellableResource : cancellableResources) {
                if (cancellableResource instanceof Closeable) {
                    ((Closeable) cancellableResource).close();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Task " + (success ? "cancelled" : "could not be cancelled. It might have completed or not started at all"));
    }
}
```

For your REST Http client related requirement you can modify the factory class something like this -

```
public class CancellableSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {

    private List<Object> cancellableResources;

    public CancellableSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    }

    public CancellableSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory(List<Object> cancellableResources) {
        this.cancellableResources = cancellableResources;
    }

    protected HttpURLConnection openConnection(URL url, Proxy proxy) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = super.openConnection(url, proxy);
        if (cancellableResources != null) {
            cancellableResources.add(connection);
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Here you need to use this factory while creating `RestTemplate` in your runnable task.

```
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(new CancellableSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory(this.cancellableResources));
```

Make sure that you pass the same list of cancellable resources that you have maintained in `CancellableTask`.

Now you need to modify the `cancel()` method in `CancellableTask` like this -

```
synchronized (lock) {
    for (Object cancellableResource : cancellableResources) {
        if (cancellableResource instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
            ((HttpURLConnection) cancellableResource).disconnect();
            success = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. When you say `if you ask future to interrupt the task`, it means I am calling cancel on future so it will interrupt my task? That's what you mean? Tell me this - If task got timedout, then I am interested in that task so I can safely terminate that task. Right? I guess `future.cancel` returns only boolean right? It will throw any exception?

Comment: Also, is it mandatory to close the http client resources as soon as the thread is interrupted? And if yes, then where I need to do that?

Comment: When you call `future.cancel(true)`, it will internally call interrupt method of the thread which is executing the task. Now it is that task's responsibility to stop its execution as soon as the thread gets interrupted.

Comment: Also it depends on the nature of task being executed to make it possible for the thread to check its own interrupted status. Something like `while(!thread.isInterrupted()) { // execute task }` .

Comment: understood now. So how can I deal with this interrupted status now? If possible, can you provide an example how would I do that?

Comment: added an example in my answer. Please note your use case is different so you probably have to implement it in little bit different way than the one which i explained but you should more or less get the direction of how to terminate the threads.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for great example. Now I understood everything about thread interruption after going through your post for several days and reading on the internet. But the only thing I am confuse is how do I handle RestTemplate interruption since I don't see RestTemplate throws InterruptedException. Also, how do I find out that my tasks got interrupted so I shouldn't do anything instead terminate cleanly? Is there any listener kind of thing? If you are around, I can have a quick chat on this.

Comment: @david : I have added some more stuff add the end of my answer to help you able to terminate the http connections through `RestTemplate`. Basically i just extended `simpleClientHttpRequestFactory` which RestTemplate uses and overridden the `openConnection()` method to add the `HttpURLConnection` instance to the `cancellableResources` list passed through your task. So when you `cancel()` the task it gets the HttpURLConnection from that list and disconnects it.