# How can I interrupt RestTemplate call as soon as my thread is interrupted?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, resttemplate, interrupted-exception

I need to make a library in which I will have synchronous and asynchronous feature.

- `executeSynchronous()` - waits until I have a result, returns the result.
- `executeAsynchronous()` - returns a Future immediately which can be processed after other things are done, if needed.

**Core Logic of my Library**

The customer will use our library and they will call it by passing `DataKey` builder object. We will then construct a URL by using that `DataKey` object and make a HTTP client call to that URL by executing it and after we get the response back as a JSON String, we will send that JSON String back to our customer as it is by creating `DataResponse` object. Some customer will call `executeSynchronous()` and some might call `executeAsynchronous()` so that's why I need to provide two method separately in my library.

Interface:

```
public interface Client {

    // for synchronous
    public DataResponse executeSynchronous(DataKey key);

    // for asynchronous
    public Future<DataResponse> executeAsynchronous(DataKey key);
}
```

And then I have my `DataClient` which implements the above `Client` interface:

```
public class DataClient implements Client {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    // for synchronous call
    @Override
    public DataResponse executeSynchronous(DataKey key) {
        DataResponse dataResponse = null;
        Future<DataResponse> future = null;

        try {
            future = executeAsynchronous(key);
            dataResponse = future.get(key.getTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            PotoLogging.logErrors(ex, DataErrorEnum.TIMEOUT_ON_CLIENT, key);
            dataResponse = new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.TIMEOUT_ON_CLIENT, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
            // does this looks right?
            future.cancel(true); // terminating tasks that have timed out
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            PotoLogging.logErrors(ex, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_ERROR, key);
            dataResponse = new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_ERROR, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
        }

        return dataResponse;
    }

    //for asynchronous call
    @Override
    public Future<DataResponse> executeAsynchronous(DataKey key) {
        Future<DataResponse> future = null;

        try {
            Task task = new Task(key, restTemplate);
            future = executor.submit(task); 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            PotoLogging.logErrors(ex, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_ERROR, key);
        }

        return future;
    }
}
```

Simple class which will perform the actual task:

```
public class Task implements Callable<DataResponse> {

    private DataKey key;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public Task(DataKey key, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.key = key;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public DataResponse call() {
        DataResponse dataResponse = null;
        String response = null;

        try {
            String url = createURL();
            response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

            // it is a successful response
            dataResponse = new DataResponse(response, DataErrorEnum.NONE, DataStatusEnum.SUCCESS);
        } catch (RestClientException ex) {
            PotoLogging.logErrors(ex, DataErrorEnum.SERVER_DOWN, key);
            dataResponse = new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.SERVER_DOWN, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            PotoLogging.logErrors(ex, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_ERROR, key);
            dataResponse = new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_ERROR, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
        }

        return dataResponse;
    }

    // create a URL by using key object
    private String createURL() {
        String url = somecode;
        return url;
    }
}
```

When I started working on this solution, I was not terminating the tasks that have timed out. I was reporting the timeout to the client, but the task continues to run in the thread pool (potentially occupying one of my limited 10 threads for a long time). So I did some research online and I found out that I can cancel my tasks those have timed out by using cancel on future as shown below -

```
future.cancel(true);
```

But if I am doing like this as shown in my above solution, then do I need to close any other resources like `RestTemplate` as soon as thread is interrupted? If yes, then how would I do that? Also, can we interrupt `RestTemplate` calls? Since I tried calling cancel on my future as soon as the task got timed out but I guess my thread doesn't got interrupted.

Should we always be terminating the tasks that have got timed out? If we don't do that then what might be the impact I will have? Will it affect my performance?

Is there any better solution to deal with this case with my current setup?

Comment: Refer the answer from -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130563/how-can-i-terminate-tasks-that-have-timed-out-in-multithreading/29130927#29130927

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes it is not possible to interrupt thread especially when thread performs blocking operations on Socket.

So instead of cancelling the task when it timeouts, you should rather set timeouts on http connection.

Unfortunately timeousts are set per Connection Factory and RestTemplate, thus each request must use it's own RestTemplate.

You can create new RestTemplate per task, or reuse previusly created templates using ThreadLocal or resource pooling.

For example the task using Thread local might look like below:

```
    public class Task implements Callable<DataResponse> {

    private DataKey key;

    private ThreadLocal<RestTemplate> restTemplateThreadLocal =
            ThreadLocal.withInitial(()->new RestTemplate(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()));

    public Task(DataKey key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    private SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory getConnectionFactory(){
        return (SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory)restTemplateThreadLocal.get().getRequestFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public DataResponse call() {
        DataResponse dataResponse = null;
        String response = null;

        try {
            String url = createURL();
            //it is up to you, how to set connection and read timeouts from provided key.getTimeout
            getConnectionFactory().setConnectTimeout(1000);
            getConnectionFactory().setReadTimeout(key.getTimeout());
            response = restTemplateThreadLocal.get().getForObject(url, String.class);

            // it is a successful response
            dataResponse = new DataResponse(response, DataErrorEnum.NONE, DataStatusEnum.SUCCESS);
        } catch (RestClientException ex) {
            PotoLogging.logErrors(ex, DataErrorEnum.SERVER_DOWN, key);
            dataResponse = new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.SERVER_DOWN, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            PotoLogging.logErrors(ex, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_ERROR, key);
            dataResponse = new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_ERROR, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
        }

        return dataResponse;
    }

    // create a URL by using key object
    private String createURL() {
        String url = somecode;
        return url;
    }
   }
```

BTW.
Spring also provides AsyncRestTemplate, which may make your code simpler.
If used with Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory you can get NIO based client connections. In such case, you should be able to interrupt your tasks even while it makes Http connection.

Short sample below. It uses NIO thus you does not have to care if the request is really cancelled after Timeout.

```
        URI url = new URI("http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-college-of-dupage-investigation-met-20150330-story.html");
        Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory asyncRequestFactory = new Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory();
        AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate(asyncRequestFactory);
        ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> entity = asyncRestTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
        System.out.println("entity.get() = " + entity.get());
        asyncRequestFactory.destroy();
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed suggestion. Is there any big difference between [AsyncRestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html) and [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client). If I need to use AsyncRestTemplate in my current setup then how will I use it? Can you provide an example for that as well if possible. It will help me to understand better?

Comment: In short, using AsyncRestTemplate you could avoid using Executors and creating tasks - because such template by default returns Future. I can show you how to do it next week unless I find some free time this weekend.

Comment: Thanks for edit. So you are suggesting, I should use AsyncRestTemplate along with Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory and then only I will be able to cancel the HTTP request if it is taking too much time?

Comment: If you use AsyncRestTemplate and Netty request factory then request uses non blocking IO which is performed in a few threads managed by Netty. Client code will wait on Future on another thread. Using NIO allows you to execute high number of concurrent requests despite of low count of IO threads. This diminished the need to really cancel request - Future.get(timeout) is enough. Theoretically NIO call can be interrupted but in described model (where call is in separate thread, and you can invoke many request per thread) this does not make sense.

Comment: ok got it. Tell me one more thing, if I don't use Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory with AsyncRestTemplate and I just use AsyncRestTemplate directly, then will it still be non blocking IO or I need to use Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory along with AsyncRestTemplate for this?

Comment: There is also HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory which also uses non blocking calls. However by default, AsyncRestTamplete uses blocking calls and request per thread. Using AsyncRestTemplate(AsyncListenableTaskExecutor taskExecutor) you get almost the same as in your example

Comment: hey I have one more question. By any chance do you know what is the difference between `Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory` and `HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory`? How to decide which one to use and when?

Comment: Both implementations are similar. You can choose based on their capabilities or look at the http://allenxwang.blogspot.com/2013/10/netty-httpasyncclient-and-httpclient.html . Anyway, at any time, you can easily swap implemetation if you find any issues.

Answer (score 7):

It [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415969/spring-resttemplate-not-allowing-cancel-interruptedexception) that a call to a `RestTemplate` cannot be interrupted or canceled. Even if the "kludge" using a callback is utilized, the `RestTemplate` might have resources locked up internally, waiting for the response before invoking the callback.

When the underlying socket is accessible, network I/O can be aborted by closing the socket from another thread. For example, a timer can be started to close the socket after a timeout elapses. Or, if you want an indefinite timeout that is sensitive to interrupts (due to a user pressing a "Cancel" button, for example), you can submit a task that waits indefinitely but responds to interrupts by closing the socket.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the authors of `RestTemplate` provided this capability.

Yes, you should clean up resources that are no longer needed because of task cancellation or expiration. Yes, it will affect performance. If your thread pool has a limited number of threads, eventually all will be stuck in defunct tasks. If it has an unlimited number of threads, eventually memory will become exhausted.