# Interrupt called on a thread doesn't throw Interrupted Exception when the thread is blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

I am trying to implement a blocking queue(only on consumer side) with ReentrantLock and conditions but am running into a state where the JVM doesn't terminate. The strange thing is that one thread gets interrupted but the other doesn't. I am sure I am making some mistake but just can't figure out what.

EDIT:

Main Question: Why does only one thread throw an interruptedexception when both the threads are blocking on condition.await

So the code below is just an example that i created. The main problem was to develop a producer-consumer implementation in which I had to create a simulation class which spawned two kinds of threads, customers and cooks, which were synchronized based on a Reentrant lock. After some operations were performed(customers adding orders and cooks performing serving those orders),I call join on customer threads to make sure that all orders have been processed and then to stop the cook threads, I called interrupt on the cook threads to terminate them. But only one thread throws interruptedexception and the second one doesn't. Why is that? since both the threads are blocking on await.

My code is as follows:

Thread class:

```
public class InterruptedThread implements Runnable{

    private final Lock lock;
    private final Condition condition;
    private final Queue<Integer> orderQueue;


    public InterruptedThread(Lock lock, Condition condition,Queue<Integer> orderQueue)
    {
        this.lock = lock;
        this.condition = condition;
        this.orderQueue = orderQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{
        while(true)
        {
            this.lock.lockInterruptibly();
            while(orderQueue.size() == 0 && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
                   System.out.println("Inside blocking wait" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                   condition.await();
            }

            int i = orderQueue.poll().intValue();
            System.out.println("Value read:" + i + "by thread" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            this.lock.unlock();


        }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Interrupted exception" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            this.condition.signalAll();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

        }

    }

}
```

Main class:

```
public class ExplicitLockCondition {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Queue<Integer> orderQueue = new LinkedList<>();
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition testCondition = lock.newCondition();

        Thread[] ths = new Thread[2];
        for(int i=0; i<ths.length;i++)
        {
            ths[i] = new Thread(new InterruptedThread(lock, testCondition,orderQueue));
            ths[i].start();
        }

        lock.lock();

        orderQueue.add(1);
        lock.unlock();

        lock.lock();
        orderQueue.add(2);
        lock.unlock();

        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ExplicitLockCondition.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        lock.lock();
        orderQueue.add(-99);
        lock.unlock();


        for(int i=0; i<ths.length;i++)
        {
            ths[i].interrupt();

        }
        System.out.println("After loop exited!!!");
        for(int i=0; i<ths.length;i++)
        {
        System.out.println("Interrupted thread:" + ths[i].getName() +"with interrupt flag:" + ths[0].isInterrupted());
        }

        for(int i=0; i<ths.length;i++)
        {
            try {
                ths[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ExplicitLockCondition.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Program exited!!!");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
condition.await();
```

but the only place you `signal` it is in the `catch` block.

In a typical run of your application, your `InterruptedThread` (let's call it `it1`) will enter the `while` loop and `await` on the `condition`, putting itself in a waiting state. Your `main` thread will do a bunch of things and eventually interrupt `it1`. You'll note the javadoc of [`Condition#await()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await--) states

> In all cases, before this method can return the current thread must
>   re-acquire the lock associated with this condition.

So thread `it2` reacquires the lock and because it's been interrupted

> If the current thread:
>
> - has its interrupted status set on entry to this method; or
> - is interrupted while waiting and interruption of thread suspension is supported,
>
> **then `InterruptedException` is thrown** and the current thread's
>   interrupted status is cleared.

So execution leaves the `while` block and goes to the `catch`. During this time, your thread `it2` still owns the lock, since nothing `unlock`ed it. The `catch` block then calls

```
this.condition.signalAll();
```

which signals the `condition`. Thread `it1` then completes normally. However, the `Lock` is still locked and nothing can acquire it which is why your other `InterruptedThread` cannot continue from within its

```
condition.await();
```

You basically have to manage locking and unlocking your `Lock` better.

Comment: Thank you, the lock was not being surrendered by that thread, I have added better unlocking code now.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have similar question on `InterruptedException` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159184/how-can-i-interrupt-resttemplate-call-as-soon-as-my-thread-is-interrupted) which is regarding interrupting the `RestTemplate` calls. If possible, can you help me out. I know you have helped me a lot on various RestTemplate question so you might be able to help me out on this as well. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am still not able to figure out a good way to deal with my current problem.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Are you around? Sorry for contacting you like this again. if you have some time today, we can chat on my silly question on which I am stuck for a long time.

Comment: @david Hi. I am around, but I don't have an answer for that question. I might look at it again later.

Answer (score 0):

a) you never signal the condition after you insert a value to your queue

b) your thread will leave

```
while(orderQueue.size() == 0 && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
```

if it is interrupted, and then tried to poll the value from the queue.
If there is no value there, the null will be returned and you end up with uncaught null pointer exception but the lock will never be unlock.

Allways

```
lock.lock()l
try {
...
} finally {
lovk.unlovk();
```

}

Comment: Thank you, I followed the pattern you suggested to refactor my code, it works now.