# Get result from callable after each task completes

Tags: java, multithreading, callable

I would like to get result from each callable task that are already submitted to a pool.

Eg:

- I have 5 callable task, Each task wait for 5 seconds
- I Submitted 5callable task to fixed thread pool 5
- Shall i get notification if 2 nd callable task completes its work ?

  ```
  public class MyCallable implements Callable<Result> {

      Result result =null;
      public MyCallable(int id, String name) {
          result=new Result(id, name);
      };

      @Override
      public Result call() throws Exception {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          return result;
      }

      public static void main(String args[]){
          ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
          List<Future<Result>> list = new ArrayList<Future<Result>>();
          Callable<Result> callable = null; 

          for(int i=0; i< 10; i++){
            callable = new MyCallable( i, "t"+i);
            Future<Result> future = executor.submit(callable);
            list.add(future);
          }

          for(Future<Result> fut : list){
            try {
               Result res = fut.get();
               System.out.println(new Date()+" Thread name "+res.getName() +" ID "+res.getId());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
     executor.shutdown();
   }

  }

  class Result {

    int id;
    String name;

    public int getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public Result(int id, String name) {
       super();
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
    }

  }
  ```

In the above example future.get method will call after processing 5 threads by excutor service.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You want to be notified when each tasks finishes it's job or when all are done?

Comment: @Slimu I want to be notified when each tasks finishes it's job

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346927/java-callable-futuretask-excecuter-how-to-listen-to-finished-task?rq=1